# Stack calls are out of code segment?

Tags: debugging, windbg, visual-studio-debugging, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I have a crash dump from our user on Windows 10 PC. Visual Studio 2015 shows me the following stack:

```
    comctl32.dll!`DuiTelemetry::Instance(void)'::`2'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'wrapper''(void)   Unknown
    comctl32.dll!CLVDrawItemManager::ComputeTextWidth(int,int,int,struct LVFAKEDRAW *,struct tagLVITEMW *,unsigned short *,int) Unknown
    app.exe!006e0065()  C++
    app.exe!00730075()  Unknown
    user32.dll!_NtUserMessageCall@28()  Unknown
    user32.dll!RealDefWindowProcWorker()    Unknown
    user32.dll!DefWindowProcW() Unknown
    user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()   Unknown
    user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
    user32.dll!CallWindowProcW()    Unknown
    mfc120u.dll!CWnd::DefWindowProcW(unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 1116 C++
    mfc120u.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 2095  C++
    mfc120u.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd, HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 285    C++
    mfc120u.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 434 C++
```

Symbols for my app.exe are loaded. But stack still shows only addresses of the functions, not their names. Why?

**Addition #1:**

I've performed the steps provided by magicandre1981. Symbols are loaded.
Here's the proof Thomas Weller asked for:

```
0:000> lm m app
start    end        module name
002e0000 00872000   app      # (private pdb symbols)  c:\work\source\app\branch\app3\bin\release.1627\app.pdb
```

The stack is even more crazy now:

```
0018cc74 7328d822 0018cf04 03652948 73274560 comctl32!`DuiTelemetry::Instance'::`2'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'wrapper''+0x89f
0018cec4 006e0065 00200074 006f004e 00650074 comctl32!CLVDrawItemManager::ComputeTextWidth+0x7d
0018ceec 00730075 00610075 006c006c 00200079 app!_CT??_R0?AVlogic_errorstd+0xd095
0018cf90 00650074 006e0072 00740065 00410020 app!ssl3_ciphers+0x7a5
0018cf94 006e0072 00740065 00410020 00630072 app!AfxWinMain+0x43e9e
0018d094 00650074 002e0073 004e0020 0074006f app!_CT??_R0?AVlogic_errorstd+0xd0a2
0018d134 00650074 0074006e 002e0073 00000000 app!AfxWinMain+0x43e9e
0018d158 77a2897c 77a04d98 000103fe 00000020 app!AfxWinMain+0x43e9e
0018d15c 77a04d98 000103fe 00000020 00010414 user32!NtUserMessageCall+0xc
0018d258 77a04bbe 014ffb60 00000000 0018d74c user32!RealDefWindowProcWorker+0x148
0018d2a8 77a284f3 00010412 0000004e 00056789 user32!DefWindowProcW+0x11e
0018d2d4 77a06c40 4b8bd2be 00010412 0018d37c user32!_InternalCallWinProc+0x2b
0018d37c 77a069d7 77d0ab50 00000000 0000004e user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f0
0018d3b8 712299aa 77d0ab50 00010412 0000004e user32!CallWindowProcW+0x97
0018d3d8 7122a918 0000004e 00056789 0018d74c mfc120u!CWnd::DefWindowProcW+0x46
0018d3f4 71228f33 0000004e 712482d1 71228f86 mfc120u!CWnd::WindowProc+0x39
0018d464 71229155 03669d50 00010412 0000004e mfc120u!AfxCallWndProc+0x99
71228f86 efefdee8 fff08bff 2a1b4415 68468971 mfc120u!AfxWndProc+0x34
```

ssl3_ciphers is not a function at all. It's an array defined in OpenSSL library.

Comment: I believe the stack does not know your function name but only the return address of the function.

Comment: Gertjan, why did you decide to waste my time? :) I know it does not. That's why modules' symbols are required to show the functions' names.

Comment: load the dmp in windbg, point to the MS symbol server and also to your private PDBs, run **!sym noisy;.reload /f /v** and look that your symbols are loaded and if the symbol file foryour app gots loaded run **!analyze -v**.

Comment: Random thought: are you sure you've loaded the right symbols for the particular build of the application the user is running?  (For example, loading the symbols from the debug build won't help if the user is running the release build.)

Comment: Yes, please provide proof of the fact that your symbols are loaded properly, e.g. by `lm m app`

Comment: Done in Addition #1.

Comment: `ssl3_ciphers` may be in your app due to static linking I'd say. The high offset indicates that the symbols don't match and that `ssl3_ciphers` is just the last known symbol that was found, no matter what type it is. Are you sure that `.symopt` doesn't have flag 40 (load anything) turned on? If so, turn it off with `.symopt- 0x40`

Comment: Yes, I understand all of this. Yes, I'm sure that flag 40 is not set (just checked it for you :) ). Also, Visual Studio never uses this flag, it can't load incorrect symbols at all.. That's why I'm asking about this strange situation.. It seems to me as a some stack damage aftermath.

Comment: .symopt+ 0x40 loads PDBs even if they don't match exactly. Try this and run .reload again

Comment: for what? it loads all the symbols already. There is not modules w/o symbols loaded for them in this dump.

Comment: the large offset at **app!AfxWinMain+0x43e9e** shows that there are symbol issues and Windbg uses the export table data

Comment: No, see Tomas explanation regarding ssl3_ciphers in the stack. This is the same thing. Btw, just checked as you asked - got the same result.